# Авторизация на сайте через POST запрос в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, post, авторизация

После авторизации нужно проверить один .PHP, который выдаст мои данные. 
Но как отправить POST запрос так, чтоб cookie запоминались?

Comment: @An0nimchic, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

```
var form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("key", "value");

var data = form.data; // Данные в byte[]
var headers = form.headers; // Заголовки, если нужны

var www = new WWW("url", data, headers);

yield return www;

// Тут обрабатываем результат типа www.responseHeaders
```